# How to log JDBC response errors in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, benchmarking

I want to debug a script that connects to a few JDBC Connections and fires JDBC Requests at them. While it is broken the output might look like this:

```
summary +     34 in 00:00:08 =    4.0/s Avg:  3890 Min:   399 Max:  7535 Err:    34 (100.00%) Active: 32 Started: 32 Finished: 0
summary +    146 in 00:00:30 =    4.8/s Avg:  6443 Min:   199 Max: 13358 Err:   146 (100.00%) Active: 32 Started: 32 Finished: 0
summary =    180 in 00:00:39 =    4.7/s Avg:  5961 Min:   199 Max: 13358 Err:   180 (100.00%)
summary +    136 in 00:00:28 =    4.9/s Avg:  6828 Min:   196 Max: 13008 Err:   136 (100.00%) Active: 0 Started: 32 Finished: 32
summary =    316 in 00:01:07 =    4.7/s Avg:  6334 Min:   196 Max: 13358 Err:   316 (100.00%)
```

I see a 100% error rate. So these errors must appear somewhere. But I haven't been able to figure it out. Things I have tried:

- Adding a diverse set of loggers to `Log4j2.xml` like `<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="info" />`.
- Adding `-Llog_level.jmeter.protocol.jdbc=TRACE` and/or `-LALL` to my jmeter command

I get thousands of log lines in jmeter.log, but none of them even mention an error. While the script is running, they look e.g. like this:

```
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.c.GenericController: Calling next on: class org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Preparing class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting dataSource=CSDISCO
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Ignoring property 'integerQueryTimeout' in org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Ignoring property 'integerResultSetMaxRows' in org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.p.AbstractProperty: Running version, executing function
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting query=select * from trable;
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting queryArguments=
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting queryArgumentsTypes=
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting queryTimeout=
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting queryType=Select Statement
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting resultSetHandler=Store as String
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting resultSetMaxRows=
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting resultVariable=
2021-04-01 16:15:17,217 DEBUG o.a.j.t.TestBeanHelper: Setting variableNames=
```

This repeats over and over. I can't understand how hard it is to get a simple error message out of Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [JDBC Request sampler source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/sampler/JDBCSampler.java#L88):

```
try {
    if (JOrphanUtils.isBlank(getDataSource())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name for DataSoure must not be empty in " + getName());
    }

    try {
        conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection(getDataSource());
    } finally {
        res.connectEnd();
    }
    res.setResponseHeaders(DataSourceElement.getConnectionInfo(getDataSource()));
    res.setResponseData(execute(conn, res));
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    final String errCode = Integer.toString(ex.getErrorCode());
    res.setResponseMessage(ex.toString());
    res.setResponseCode(ex.getSQLState()+ " " +errCode);
    res.setResponseData(ex.getMessage(), res.getDataEncodingWithDefault());
    res.setSuccessful(false);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    res.setResponseMessage(ex.toString());
    res.setResponseCode("000");
    res.setResponseData(
            ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(ex.getMessage(), "NO MESSAGE"),
            res.getDataEncodingWithDefault());
    res.setSuccessful(false);
} finally {
    close(conn);
}
```

The exception message is being added as the response message so it'll be present in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles)

So if you open this file using text viewer of your choice - you will see the error messages there.

If you need to see them in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#sys.stdout) - you can add a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and use the code like:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    println('Sampler ' + prev.getSampleLabel() + ' failed with ' + prev.getResponseMessage())
}
```

Where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on JMeter API shorhands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)